# Sort feature class in Modelbuilder and populate new ids

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I would like to sort my feature class in a model based on coordinates stored in its attribute table. The sorting must be done on `Y_coord` descending, then `X_coord` ascending. The answer to [Sorting feature class to calculate sequential ID field using ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16752/how-to-sort-a-feature-class-and-then-calculate-a-sequential-id-field) looks like what I need, except I only have an ArcEditor Licence, and free versions of Xtools Pro and ET Geowizards. My model performs several other processes as well, so I need the sorting to be included in it. How can I perform the sort with the above limitations?

However, looking at the options in the `Sort` tool, I've realised that what I actually want to do is sort my features spatially, starting from the upper left, but to sort based on the `Shape` field requires an ArcInfo licence. The sort tool from ET Geowizards does not allow sorting on this field either. Are there other tools which could do this?

Comment: It looks like all the tools proposed in that answer are working with all license levels. I don't see any problems for ArcEditor License... Or I've missed something?

Comment: @AlexMarkov they work just fine when run manually from ArcMap, but when I try adding the `Sort Shapes` tool from the ET Toolbox into my model, it says "Tool not licensed". The XTools Pro toolbox does not contain the `Sort Features/Records` tool which is available under `Table Operations` on the ArcMap toolbar.

Comment: You are using ET GeoWizards tools instead of ArcGIS native. Try to add `Sort` tool from `Data Management \ General` toolset and `Calculate Field` from 'Data Management \ Fields`. These one's are actually stated in that answer.

Comment: According to the answer to this [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13891/reorder-a-polygon-shape-file-not-sort), the `Sort` tool requires an ArcInfo licence, so I that's why I did not consider it. I see now though that it does allow for sorting on one field only, so I guess I'll have to add two sort processes to my model.

Comment: But according to help it is licensed at all levels and I've just checked - it is running under my ArcView license.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then Alex, because it works if I sort by one field only. If I try to add a second field, or just try to sort on the `Shape` field alone, it gives `Error 000824: The tool is not licensed.`

Comment: I can't catch why do you need to sort by `Shape` field? As it is usually a BLOB field. May be you should calculate X coord and Y coord fields (centroid if not point) ?

Comment: I initially did use the coordinates of my centroids for sorting, but it was not giving me the output that I wanted. When I saw the native Sort tool could give me what I wanted by sorting on the Shape field, I tried it out, but obviously I don't have the correct licence. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using `Sort` in 10.1, sorting on the `Shape` field starting from the upper left. It did work as expected, but because the features I want to sort are irregularly shaped, the sorting does not occur in the order I want it to, i.e. from left to right then down. This is because the y coordinate of the upper left corner of a feature on the right may be slightly above that of the leftmost feature, so the rightmost feature is placed first, even though I would want the leftmost feature first.

I suppose after the initial use of the Sort tool, some Python scripting would be needed to further sort the results.

Comment: I actually had to do this the other day. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/cindygis/d08802236f05d184c097) containing the Python script.