# Removing coincident points with z values greater than minimum

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, point-cloud, duplication, spline

I am trying to run a spline interpolation on some terrestrial LiDAR data, but it keeps failing (I'm getting `error 010235 - returned error from spline process and error 010067 - error executing grid expression`).

I think it's due to the fact that there may be coincident points (ie. points with the same xy but different z values).

Can anyone suggest a way to delete the duplicate points with z values greater than the minimum? I can't do it manually because I think there may be a lot of duplicates (I tried the collect events tool, and there were many coincident points).

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44063/how-to-find-and-delete-identical-points