# Removing duplicate points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I want to remove duplicate points.

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2.

the problem is as follows:

I have 8 layers of restaurants

I made a junction of the 7 layers in one shapefile

Now I have a layer of 3000 restaurants, the problem is that there are now restaurants duplicates

I need to have a unified Shp with its comprehensive information without duplicates

I thought:

to remove duplicates I'm trying to make a buffer

impunt = restaurant

distance = 100 yards (because usually a restaurant name "A" should not be dry for another restaurant name "A"

dissolve Type = ALL (to make me one polygon in those restantantes name "A" and so to make the search easier estaurants duplicate

now want the attribute tables I pull buffer polygon registration, as this returns me only one record for all polygons

Can you tell me if usdes as having achieved record by exite polygon or other tool to search I am duplicate?

Comment: are you looking to delete instances of duplicate geometry only (point stacked on top of another point)?  or is there a scenario where, say, Taco Bell at 150 Main street is represented by two points that are 50 feet apart, when in fact it is only one location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find and delete identical points?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44063/how-to-find-and-delete-identical-points)

Comment: so i needed to know how registration could create polygon to reduce the look and focus only on those poligos more area and analyze all examples that you gave me

Answer (score 12):

Use the [Delete Identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000053000000) tool. There's also a [Find Identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Find_Identical/001700000054000000/) tool to check which features have duplicates you can use first, if you want.

Both tools need an Advanced level license.