# ModelBuilder routine to remove spatially duplicate features

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I'm attempting to build a ModelBuilder routine in ArcGIS 10.1 based off of an existing [post on Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26921/remove-spatially-duplicate-features-using-modelbuilder).  The response from 'Get Spatial' gave a great screen shot of a model that would run an input through an interative process to remove spatially duplicate features.  I've attempted to build this model on my own but have run into two problems.

1. I have been unable to get the 'Output Feature Class' at the end of the routine to recognize the Input Features as a Feedback Variable.  I've attempted making this connection through the Class Properties of the Output and the connect tool by picking the output and then the input.

What sort of restrictions on the Feedback Variable could be preventing me from making this connection?

2. I've attempted to run the model several times without the Feedback Variable connected and gotten an error that there is no input or fields that are required.  I've entered this information in the parameters.

What reasons would cause this error to occur?  Could it be related to the missing feedback Variable?

Appreciate the help.  I may need to reconsider the use of the Feedback Variable and the design of the model if I can't get around these issues.  Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 4):

you can use [Delete identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000053000000) tool, and may be avoid using Model.

Comment: `Delete Identical` is only available at the Advanced licence level, the OP has not indicated which licence is available.

Answer (score 2):

There is another free "Remove Identical" Tool available from [TypeConvert](http://code.google.com/p/typeconvert/).
It can be used from a toolbar but also as a tool in ModelBuilder.
It helped me solve my "Delete Identical"-problems